# Interpretation of logn^logn?

Tags: math, logarithm

How should I interpret [image]

How do I interpret this? One way is to take it as logn(logn) and other is [image]. Both would be giving different answers.

For eg:
Taking base 2 and n=1024, in first case we get 10*10 as ans. In the second case, we get 10^10 as ans or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: mmm toothie, correct if i am wrong but (log(x) n)^ (log(x) n) != (log(log(x) n)n)

Comment: @Victor yes, thats right.

Comment: I believe, but am not sure, that this would typically be taken to mean "log(n^(log(n)))". You might ask for further clarification at the mathematics stack exchange site.

Comment: @Patrick87 then this would become logn*logn. Right?

Comment: Correct. log(a^b) = blog(a)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `log(n^log n)=(log n)^2`, I would assume that `log n^log n` should be interpreted as `(log n)^(log n)`.  Otherwise, there's no point in the exponentiation.  But whoever wrote that down for you should have clarified.

Answer (score 2):

From a programmer's viewpoing a good way to better understand a function is to plot it at different parts of its domain.

But what is the domain of `f(x) := ln(x)^ln(x)`? Well, given that the exponent is not an integer, the base cannot be smaller than `1`. Why? Because ln(x) is negative for `0 < x < 1` and it is not even defined for `x <= 0`.

But what about `x = 1`. Given that `ln(1) = 0`, we would get `0^0`, which is not defined either. So, let's plot `f(x)` for `x` between: `1.000001` and `1.1`. We get:

[image]

The plot reveals that there would be no harm in extending the definition of `f(x)` at `1` in this way (let me use pseudocode here):

```
f(x) := if x = 1 then 1 else ln(x)^ln(x)
```

Now, let's see what happens for larger values of `x`. Here is a plot between `1` and `10`:

[image]

This plot is also interesting because it exposes a singular behavior between `1` and `3`, so let's plot that part of the domain to see it better:

[image]

There are a couple of questions that one could ask by looking at this plot. For instance, what is the value of `x` such that `f(x)=1`? Mm... this value is visibly between `2.7` and `2.8` (much closer to `2.7`). And what number do we know that is a little bit larger than `2.7`? This number should be related to the `ln` function, right? Well, `ln` is logarithm in base `e` and the number `e` is something like `2.71828182845904...`. So, it looks like a good candidate, doesn't it? Let's see:

```
f(e) = ln(e)^ln(e) = 1^1 = 1!
```

So, yes, the answer to our question is `e`.

Another interesting value of `x` is the one where the curve has a minimum, which lies somewhere between `1.4` and `1.5`. But since this answer is getting too long, I will stop here. Of course, you can keep plotting and answering your own questions as you happen to encounter them. And remember, you can use iterative numeric algorithms to find values of `x` or `f(x)` that, for whatever reason, appear interesting to you.

Comment: Huh?  You've got an incredibly long answer, but you assume an answer to OP's question in the second paragraph (`ln(x)^ln(x)`) without comment.